# find rpms installed in an Archived root filesystem

Tags: linux, rpm

I have archive of a root filesystem, is there is any way I can find installed rpms in that archive.

It is a tar archive, exported from docker image. I have exported docker image using save command and it is root fs from one of layer inside that archive.

Comment: What format is the archive?

Comment: thanks @larsks, it is bz2

Comment: A bz2...what? Is it a disk image, a tar archive, something else? Exactly how did you create it? Details are important and will enable us to provide you with a useful answer.

Comment: thanks @larsks. it is a tar archive, It is exported from docker image. I have exported docker image using save command and it is root fs from one of layer inside that archive.

Comment: Please be sure to add any details also to the original question and not only to the comments - comments are subject to removal without notice, and it is often painful to read through the comment section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extract the `/var/lib/rpm` directory from the tar file and then run `rpm` against that directory. E.g:

```
$ tar -xf layer.tar var/lib/rpm
$ rpm --dbpath $PWD/var/lib/rpm -qa
```

You could also use `docker import` to create a new image from that layer and then `docker run --rm newimage rpm -qa`, but this assumes that e.g. the `rpm` binary is included in the image (this is not always the case, even for images built from rpm-based distributions).

Comment: thankyou so much, its really great solution !!!